# .NET Single file - include files other than libraries (e.g. *.conf)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

Is there any way in .NET 8 how to put a *.conf file in single file EXE?

I need to bundle Firebird embedded in my application. Using IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract will include all Firebird dlls, but one file is missing - .conf.

There is also an IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract option which will inlcude everything, but I prefer only the necessary files to be self-extracted.

Comment: What files are included in "everything" that are not "necessary"?